# Video List in Portrait; Video playback in Landscape

Tags: iphone, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a list of videos that a user can select from to watch.  All of the videos are included in the app resources and played locally.

I have everything working great except for one thing.  I can't figure out how to force the video playback into landscape mode.

I'm using this code to display the video player when a video is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VideoPlayerViewController *detailViewController = [[VideoPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.delegate = self;

    detailViewController.contentPath = [[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];

    [self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

My player class, VideoPlayerViewController loads the player using the contentPath set in the above code and plays the video.

I can rotate my phone and it switches to landscape but if I rotate my phone back to portrait the video rotates as well.  My player has the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Any ideas why it allows the rotation back to portrait and how I can start the playback in landscape?

I'm looking for similar functionality as the native YouTube app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in VideoPlayerViewController viewDidLoad method and in shouldautorotate method:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

 [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
 [[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
 [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```